# How do I make a Swing JComponent a bigger mouse target?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I have a JPanel that contains a bunch of Swing JComponents, including some JSeparators that may be only one or two pixels wide.  I want to let my users drag the items around, but it can be rather difficult to hit a one or two pixel wide line.  Is there a way that I can give those JSeparators a wider "target" region for mouse clicks?  The only thing I've been able to think of is to have my mouse handler listen for clicks on the JPanel, and if it gets any, run through the list of JSeparators, looking to see if any of them are within a couple of pixels of the mouse click.

Should that work?  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

Add a fat [`EmptyBorder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/EmptyBorder.html) to the component.

If it already has a border, you can set a compound border using the current border then the empty border, or simpler, add the empty border (and listener) to a panel that contains the component.  The latter will work better for components such as `JButton`, which have borders that change according to state and focus.